# Why Azure appsettings encoding bring me wrong chars?

Tags: node.js, azure, encoding, azure-web-app-service

I have a problem whit the azure appsettings encoding.

I have a node.js application deployed into an app service. When calling the environment variables using process.env, the values  are comming in wrong encoding. I  was expect a "utf8" encoding that supports chars like "ñ", "ó", "í", "á", "é", "ú" but instead of that, I get chars like "¢", "£", " ", etc.

Could you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly same thing on my side.

There seems some encoding problem with `process.env` as on Kudu(`https://<webappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/Env.cshtml#envVariables`) the app setting could show as expected. Also in a .net app I was able to get the correct string.

Comparing the input with the decoded result we got, I found it may be encoded using [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) and decoded using another charset like [win1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

So one workaround is to encode the string which have been somehow formatted incorrectly, and decode it again with the charset it's encoded. Install [iconv-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv-lite) and try following code snippet.

```
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');

var buf = iconv.encode(process.env.MYTEST, 'win1252');
var result = iconv.decode(buf, 'ibm437');
```

Comment: Thanks! Your advice was so usefull. It resolves my issue.

Comment: @jerry-liu This works great! Almost. I'm using Swedish characters. The code works for characters _åäö ÄÖ_ but not for _Å_... Any idea what could be wrong or what to do? I'm at a loss.