# Azure Application settings set charset UTF-8

Tags: azure

I have an issue fetching from my Node.js application settings from Azure - characters are not shown same from Azure. For example using **process.env.TEMPORARY_WARNING** it results in: "Vissa anv„ndare upplever problem just nu." - but on Azure looks like below.

"Å" becomes "†",
"Ä" becomes "„",
"ö" becomes "”",

```
{
    "name": "TEMPORARY_WARNING",
    "value": "Vissa användare upplever problem just nu."
    "slotSetting": true
}
```

I think I somehow need to set charset to UTF-8, but cannot find any solution to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's problem with **process.env** , as a workaround you can use[iconv-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv-lite) to encode your settings and decode them when you need ,

```
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');

var buf = iconv.encode(process.env.MYTEST, 'win1252');
var result = iconv.decode(buf, 'ibm437');
```

Source : [Why Azure appsettings encoding bring me wrong chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53363462/why-azure-appsettings-encoding-bring-me-wrong-chars)